# Tracking how many cars are rented and available in a Class

Tags: java

I've been having some trouble with this code. This is an assignment for my java class.its past due but I'm going nuts just trying to figure out the problem.

Problem:

When I upload it to WileyPlus(automatic correcting server), it keeps saying that when 'int n = 14' it's expecting the result to be "24 , 15", but I get "23, 16". However, when I enter 12 I get what is expected, which is "7,5". I can't seem to find what's causing this.

With the code, it will make more sense.

```
public class RentalCar {
    private boolean rented;
    private static int availableCars = 0;
    private static int rentedCars = 0;

    public RentalCar() {
        availableCars++;
        rented = false;
    }

    public static int numAvailable() {
        return availableCars;
    }

    public static int numRented() {
        return rentedCars;
    }

    public boolean rentCar() {
        availableCars--;
        rentedCars++;
        rented = true;
        return rented;
    }

    public boolean returnCar() {
        if (rented) {
            availableCars++;
            rentedCars--;
            rented = false;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static String check(int n) {
        RentalCar[] cars = new RentalCar[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cars[i] = new RentalCar();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i + 2) {
            cars[i].rentCar();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i + 3) {
            cars[i].rentCar();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i + 4) {
            cars[i].returnCar();
        }

        return RentalCar.numRented() + " " + RentalCar.numAvailable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Every instance of `RentalCar` you create will have the same values for `availableCars` and `rentedCars`.

Comment: @Makoto: That part seems to be correct.

Comment: @Makoto I think that's the point; it's tracking counts.

Comment: @Rimshot: When renting a car, you don't check if it's already rented.

Answer (score 3):

In `returnCar()` you check, if the car you are trying to return is rented. In `rentCar()` you don't do that. It seems you can rent a car that's already rented. Try to prevent renting cars that are already rented.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean rentCar() {
    if (!rented) {
        availableCars--;
        rentedCars++;
        rented = true;
    }
    return rented;
}
```

(check if car is already rented in `rentCar()`)

Also, I don't understand the purpose of the return value, i.e. you might as well do

```
public void rentCar() {
    if (!rented) {
        availableCars--;
        rentedCars++;
        rented = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps he meant for the return value to indicate whether the operation succeeded or not (though that is not what it is doing).